# join nested queries in from clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, db2, subquery

Can you tell me what I need to manipulate in this query to get it working?

```
select C.ID from 
(select A.ID from CUSTOMERS A inner join PROFILES B on A.ID=B.ID where CTR='67564' and CST_CD in 
('G','H')) as C 
inner join
(select ID from RELATION_CODES where R_CD='KC') as R
on C.ID=R.ID
```

The individual inner queries are working just fine and giving correct results, not sure what is the problem with `inner join` in from clause..

Comment: If you're getting an error what is it? What do you want results to look like? What does your sample data set look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure I'm understanding your question, but this should be able to be rewritten without the subqueries:

```
select c.id 
from customers c
    join profiles p on c.id = p.id 
    join relation_codes rc on rc.id = c.id
where ctr = '67564' 
    and cst_cd in ('G','H')
    and rc.r_cd = 'KC'
```

If this isn't working, please provide your table structure and sample data and expected results.  This should get you pretty close though.

---

I have to ask, is the `id` field in the `relation_codes` table and the `profiles` table the same as the `id` in the `customers` table.  Perhaps you need to identify how your tables are related.

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Your join query also gives same results...thanks...anyways query in question also works fine for me...I was using `select * from CUSTOMERS A....` instead of `select A.ID from CUSTOMERS A.....` so it got confused which ID to fetch...